# c++ Variadic Macro Compile error

Tags: c++, c, macros, variadic

Following the stackoverflow question: "Variadic macros with zero arguments, and commas", I tried:

```
#define MAKE_TEMPLATE(...) template <typename T, ## __VA_ARGS__ >

MAKE_TEMPLATE()
struct Testing{};
```

Compiler gives: *error: expected identifier before '>' token*

But *g++ -E main.cpp* (to get macro expansion) show:

```
template <typename T >
struct Testing{};
```

And with:

```
MAKE_TEMPLATE(typename U)
struct Testing{};
```

It compile OK.
Whats missing?

Comment: But the gcc docs says:
"if the variable arguments are omitted or empty, the ‘##’ operator causes the preprocessor to remove the comma before it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro:
GCC supports the following (non-portable) extension: `## __VA_ARGS__`

Comment: Well, any alternative?